# Convert hexadecimal value to timestamp/date and time

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, hex

Hi I have hexadecimal string of time stamp generated by **MSC** (is a neighbouring base stations keeps a record of the location of the mobile subscribers). Now I want to convert hexadecimal string to human readable date and time.

I tried as follows but I'm not able to convert:

```
        String s = "1508221325112B0530";
        long longVaue = new BigInteger(s, 16).longValue();

        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(longVaue);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

Output : `18573217-01-15 09:15:35`

It is not printing the year, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what the correct output is?

Comment: @shmosel sorry no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your date is in picoseconds. Try this:

```
long longVaue = new BigInteger(s, 16).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000)).longValue();
```

Should print out `1982-04-18 12:47:57`.

Another (likelier?) possibility is that it's actually a *decimal* number, with some other value delimited by a "B":

```
long longVaue = Long.parseLong(s.split("B")[0]);
```

Prints `2017-10-16 11:22:05`.

Note: My timezone is PST. Your results may differ slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply first answer might right but not second answer because the data what i got is a live data generated by MSC.

Comment: can you tell me why we need to divide the value by 1000000000...?

Comment: @RajeshHatwar 1 millisecond = 1,000,000,000 picoseconds